# How to create web crawler in java?

Tags: java, android

Hi i want to create a web crawler in java in which i want to retrive some data like title, description from the web page and store the datas in database

Comment: I like HtmlUnit, but I don't know how well it would work on Android...

Comment: Tell me how to use HtmlUnit to create web crawler.First i want to parse some datas and store it in db.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do your own use the included [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) in the android [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html).

Example usage of HttpClient (you only need to parse out the :

```
public class HttpTest {
    public static void main(String... args) 
    throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        crawlPage("http://www.google.com/");
    }

    static Set<String> checked = new HashSet<String>();

    private static void crawlPage(String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        if (checked.contains(url))
            return;

        checked.add(url);

        System.out.println("Crawling: " + url);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        Reader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());

            Links links = new Links();
            new ParserDelegator().parse(reader, links, true);

            for (String link : links.list) 
                if (link.startsWith("http://"))
                    crawlPage(link);

        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }



    static class Links extends HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback {

        List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

        public void handleStartTag(HTML.Tag t, MutableAttributeSet a, int pos) {
            if (t == HTML.Tag.A)
                list.add(a.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use crawler4j. Crawler4j is an open source Java crawler which provides a simple interface for crawling the Web. You can setup a multi-threaded web crawler in few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this example: 
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ThirdParty/WebCrawler/

And to existing open source crawlers:
http://java-source.net/open-source/crawlers/java-web-crawler

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebCollector:  https://github.com/CrawlScript/WebCollector

Demo based on WebCollector 2.05:

```
import cn.edu.hfut.dmic.webcollector.crawler.BreadthCrawler;
import cn.edu.hfut.dmic.webcollector.model.Links;
import cn.edu.hfut.dmic.webcollector.model.Page;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

/**
 * Crawl news from yahoo news
 *
 * @author hu
 */
public class YahooCrawler extends BreadthCrawler {

    /**
     * @param crawlPath crawlPath is the path of the directory which maintains
     * information of this crawler
     * @param autoParse if autoParse is true,BreadthCrawler will auto extract
     * links which match regex rules from pag
     */
    public YahooCrawler(String crawlPath, boolean autoParse) {
        super(crawlPath, autoParse);
        /*start page*/
        this.addSeed("http://news.yahoo.com/");

        /*fetch url like http://news.yahoo.com/xxxxx*/
        this.addRegex("http://news.yahoo.com/.*");
        /*do not fetch url like http://news.yahoo.com/xxxx/xxx)*/
        this.addRegex("-http://news.yahoo.com/.+/.*");
        /*do not fetch jpg|png|gif*/
        this.addRegex("-.*\\.(jpg|png|gif).*");
        /*do not fetch url contains #*/
        this.addRegex("-.*#.*");
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Page page, Links nextLinks) {
        String url = page.getUrl();
        /*if page is news page*/
        if (Pattern.matches("http://news.yahoo.com/.+html", url)) {
            /*we use jsoup to parse page*/
            Document doc = page.getDoc();

            /*extract title and content of news by css selector*/
            String title = doc.select("h1[class=headline]").first().text();
            String content = doc.select("div[class=body yom-art-content clearfix]").first().text();

            System.out.println("URL:\n" + url);
            System.out.println("title:\n" + title);
            System.out.println("content:\n" + content);

            /*If you want to add urls to crawl,add them to nextLink*/
            /*WebCollector automatically filters links that have been fetched before*/
            /*If autoParse is true and the link you add to nextLinks does not match the regex rules,the link will also been filtered.*/
            // nextLinks.add("http://xxxxxx.com");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        YahooCrawler crawler = new YahooCrawler("crawl", true);
        crawler.setThreads(50);
        crawler.setTopN(100);
        //crawler.setResumable(true);
        /*start crawl with depth of 4*/
        crawler.start(4);
    }

}
```